# 2 AccessoryItems on callout showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have two info buttons showing up within my callout view for some reason. I have 3 different pin colors that are pulling information from 3 different sources. I need each button for each pin color to push to a separate view controller based on that annotation class. i have the following code so far for my 3 different pin colors:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[annotation class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (view == nil) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                    initWithAnnotation:annotation
                    reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {

            view.annotation = annotation;
        }

       if([[(Annotation*)annotation phoneNumber] isEqualToString:@"0"]){


            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
            // Create a UIButton object to add on the
            self.leftBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
            [self.leftBtn setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:self.leftBtn];

        }else{

            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;

            // Create a UIButton object to add on the
            self.rightBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
            [self.rightBtn setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [view setRightCalloutAccessoryView:self.rightBtn];

        }

        if ([[(Annotation*)annotation phoneNumber] isEqualToString:@"1"]){

            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            // Create a UIButton object to add on the
            self.leftBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [self.leftBtn setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:self.leftBtn];

        }


        return view;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And for my accessory tapped method I have the following:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)map annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

    if(view.leftCalloutAccessoryView){


        UserAnnotation *annotate = view.annotation;
        BuydealsViewController *dealsView=[[BuydealsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DealDetailsViewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        dealsView.urlString = annotate.url;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dealsView animated:YES];
}
    if(view.rightCalloutAccessoryView){

        MapDealViewController *mapDeals = [[MapDealViewController alloc] init];
        Annotation *annView = view.annotation;
        mapDeals.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        mapDeals.phoneNumber = annView.phoneNumber;
        mapDeals.address = annView.subtitle;
        mapDeals.title = annView.title;
        mapDeals.description = annView.description;
        mapDeals.value = annView.value1;
        mapDeals.discountPercent = annView.discountPercent;
        mapDeals.price = annView.price;
        mapDeals.header = annView.header;
        mapDeals.imageUrl = annView.imageUrl;
        mapDeals.url = annView.url;
        mapDeals.dealy = annView.dealy;

        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapDeals animated:YES];

}



}
```

Is there any way to make them both right buttons but click to separate views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, this may not be causing any issues currently, but it's important to point out.
This line in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[annotation class]])
```

looks wrong because *of course* `annotation` will be the same kind of class as *itself*.
This will always return `YES`.

You probably meant to write `Annotation class` with an uppercase `A` which is the class name (`annotation` with a lowercase `a` refers to the current annotation instance parameter):

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
```

**Regarding *"I have two info buttons showing up within my callout view for some reason."*:**

Look at this simplified version of the current logic in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
if (phoneNumber is "0") 
{
    ...
    [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:self.leftBtn];
}
else
{
    ....
    [view setRightCalloutAccessoryView:self.rightBtn];
}

if (phoneNumber is "1") 
{
    ....
    [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:self.leftBtn];
}
```

Notice that if phoneNumber is "1":

- The view's `rightCalloutAccessoryView` is set in the `else` since "1" is not "0",
- **And** the view's `leftCalloutAccessoryView` is set in the second `if` (since it is "1").

The logic for setting the accessory views needs to be adjusted according to what you want.

Note that you should explicitly set the view's `leftCalloutAccessoryView` or `rightCalloutAccessoryView` to `nil` when a given annotation should not have that accessory (and when other annotations might).  This is because if an annotation view is re-used, its accessory views may already be set based on the annotation it was previously used for.  So you might do something like this:

```
if (phoneNumber is "0")
{
    ...
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType...];
}
else if (phoneNumber is "1")
{
    ...
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType...];
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
}
else
{
    //some default, unexpected case handling...
    ...
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
}
```

Also, there's no need to have `leftBtn` and `rightBtn` as properties and may cause confusion or other issues.  Just declare them as local variables.

**Regarding *"Is there any way to make them both right buttons but click to separate views?"*:**

Yes.  You already have code in `viewForAnnotation` that does this:

- You can check the `annotation` object's `class` (but do it correctly using the *class* name and not the *instance* variable).
- You can cast `annotation` to your custom class and check custom property values (like `phoneNumber`).

Comment: Woah, that was awesome! Yeah, I didn't realize that I had set conditions for my MKUserLocation for annotation, and the other was for my Annotation class. Thank you, for this!